# Angular service in external package - dependency injection HttpClient undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

Suppose you have the following Angular libraries:

First library, a base service library:

```js
// base.service.ts

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export abstract class BaseService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  protected request(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.request('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:3100/CRM/v1/customers');
  }
}
```

Second library:

```js
// test.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseService } from '@company/data-access-base';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export abstract class TestService extends BaseService {
  testRequest(): Observable<any> {
    return this.request();
  }
}
```

Than you decide to use the TestService in your app.

Off course, you already imported `HttpClientModule` in the app.module.ts of your app. Then you inject TestService and try to use it:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '@company/data-access-test';

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testService.testRequest().subscribe((r) => console.log('Test ok', r))
  }
}
```

Here you get the following error in your console:

```
core.js:4610 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
    at TestService.request (company-data-access-base.js:42)
    at TestService.testRequest (company-data-access-crm.js:7)
    at HomeComponent.ngOnInit (home.component.ts:13)
    at callHook (core.js:3405)
    ...
```

How to I get HttpClient injected in the BaseService?

Answer (score 0):

Turns our that, given the fact that the injected service in the application is `TestService`, that's the service that Angular (and as far as I know any other framework's DI system) will manage.

So, easy solution, simply add a constructor to each of the services, and call the super.(httpService).

```js
// test.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseService } from '@company/data-access-base';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export abstract class TestService extends BaseService {

  // that's what was missing
  constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(httpClient);
  }

  testRequest(): Observable<any> {
    return this.request();
  }
}
```